# get an unknown string between two strings and save it in a var (Windows script)

Tags: windows, bash

The thing is that I want to do this JUST by using Windows bash utils (so it can be easily used without other applications like Cygwin/grep on other workstations).
Also this command will be in a larger script that uses the extracted string as a part of a filename.

ex: this is the line in the searched file

```
"    <DataVersion>A0C2</DataVersion>"
```

A0C2 is the string that I need but it can have a different value like X1Z4 but is always 4 alfanumeric characters long.

```
<DataVersion> and </DataVersion> are always present.
```

Also the line may occur more than once but I only need the first to be considered.

Comment: can you provide a URL to the "Windows bash utils" that you are using? Or as you say "without other apps like Cyg.... on other workstations", what is the path/name of such software you expect to have available on other workstations? Powershell should be able to do this (not an evangalist ;-) ) . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter [link](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out in the mean time the answer to my own question.

```
set ROW=
set VERSION=
for /f %%i in ( 'findstr "<DataVersion>"  file.txt' ) do @set ROW=%%i
set VERSION=%ROW:~x,y%
```

where:

- x is the number of characters you want to skip in ROW and
- y is the number of characters you want to save in VERSION

so in case

```
findstr "<DataVersion>"  file.txt
```

returns and sets ROW to this value:

```
<DataVersion>AX23</DataVersion>
```

then:

```
set VERSION=%ROW:~14,4%
```

will set VERSION to AX23